# БД без СУБД

Tags: xml, php, nosql, база-данных

Всем привет. У меня такой вопрос. Возникла необходимость сделать базу данных на `XML` (без использования СУБД). Я сделал добавление в каталог, но осталось еще предусмотреть возможность редактирования, удаления а так же поиск. Какие есть варианты сделать это без привычного `UPDATE`, `DROP` и `LIKE`? Слышал, что как-то можно переделать `XML` в объект, а там уже видно будет что делать. Насчет поиска: собирался делать через `preg_match()`, но меня стали терзать сомнение, что имя тега может совпадать с содержимым. А поиск по тегам пока еще не планируется. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: В таком случае СУБД будет являться ваша программа :)

Comment: IMHO если проектируете сами и не связаны с "тяжким наследием прошлого", то XML не самый лучший выбор.

Comment: +100500 2 @avp, есть подозрения что вы хотите что-то типа документно-ориентированной БД и просто об этом пока не знаете.

Если же свой велосипед принцип или, например, требование - не лучше ли использовать JSON?..

PS: не смотря на то, что считаю подобные движения абсолютным бредом - лично работал с довольно неплохой закрытой реализацией подобного функционала, как бы сильно я не был удивлен - работало замечательно, как по скорости так и по стабильности (правда это была целая софтина написанная на плюсах)

Comment: Я бы добавил, что если вашей целю является отвязка от серверной части, то стоит взглянуть на [sqlite](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с XML есть свои инструменты, в том числе:

- XPath (язык запросов к элементам XML-документа)
- XQuery (зык запросов обработки данных в формате XML)
- XSLT (язык преобразования XML-документов)

Используя их, вы сможете работать с XML практически как с базой данных. Пример.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<numbers>
<number>1</number>
<number>2</number>
<number>3</number>
</numbers>
```

и

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($file));
$numbers = $xml->xpath('//xml/numbers');
```

Answer (score 0):

Теги можно и не искать. :)

```
preg_match_all("/[^<\/]$search/",$str,$matches);
```